# Copying coredata relationship object with new row entry

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I have 2 entities with a one to one relationship. I have a functionality of copy in my application which copies the managedobject and creates a new entry with this object.

2 entities are actually DocMetaData and DocumentData.

DocMetaData contains document details like name, size, type and DocumentData contains the actual document. Now when i copy a document from one folder to another, a new DocMetaData entityobject should be inserted but i want that instead of creating a DocumentData object it creates a entry from the relationship itself as copying a veru big document from folder to folder could be a heavy operation.

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just copy the `DocMetaData` object and re-link the relationship:

```
document.metaData = newMetaData;
```

Note that in Core Data there is not really something like "copying" managed objects. You have to create a new one and assign all the attributes as in the original object:

```
DocMetaData *newMetaData = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:
  @"DocMetaData" inManagedObjectContext:context];
// populate the attributes of newMetaData with the existing object        
newMetaData.name = document.metaData.name; // etc.
```

Comment: Can you elaborate more on relinking and how to do it. While copying items of DocMetaData there will be few attributes value which will be changed... So cannot directly copy the objects.

Comment: Copy, modify, assign (=re-link) via the line above.

Comment: Can you give an example. When you copy this object only this object will get copied, relationship and obect linked to relationship wont get copied...

Comment: This is what exactly we are doing and we are facing problem... if suppose there are lot of document that we are copying and each document is of 25-50 MB then at some point app crash  due to memory warning. We are having recursive function to copy content in each folder to the destination. Are we missing something here.

Comment: There is no reason to keep all documents in memory. But this is another problem. You should accept this answer and open a new question. - Don't forget to up-vote.